# How to convert a String data and time including month name to Date object in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, converters

I want to convert the date in string to date object being the string "10h 57m 20s October 13 2020". How can be done? may replace firstly the h, m and s to get the format "10:57:20 October 13 2020"? As well, I tried the last format  "10:57:20 October 13 2020" to get the date with DateTimeFormat and DateTimeFormatterBuilder() but is does not work with the month or it works but the hour coverts to 00:00:00.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add which pattern(s) you tried? See also the JavaDocs for [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). You did try 4 letters to trigger the "full" text form, e.g. `MMMM`?

Comment: I tried this format: "hh:mm:ss MMMM dd yyyy" based on the reformat string that I do "10:57:20 October 13 2020".

Comment: More details on string to date conversion is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: We can give you tips, but to address all of your issues we need a [mre], please.

Comment: *to Date object* If you meant `java.util.Date`, I recommend that you do not use that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And use the `DateTimeFormatter` that you already mention for parsing (you don’t need the builder in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Like Joop Eggen already wrote, put the letters that are part of your format in single quotes in the format pattern string:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H'h' m'm' s's' MMMM d y", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This will allow you to parse like this:

```
    String dateInString = "10h 57m 20s October 13 2020";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2020-10-13T10:57:20

You shouldn’t take any interest in the old-fashioned `Date` class. However, sometimes we need to pass a `Date` to a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time. The conversion requires that we know the time zone assumed for the parsed date and time. For example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Tegucigalpa");
    Instant i = dateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(i);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Example output:

> Tue Oct 13 10:57:20 CST 2020

### Tutorial link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can place fixed letters in apostrophes.

```
"HH'h' mm'm' ss's' MMMM dd yyyy"
```

Furthermore `hh` is the 12 hour format to be combined wiht `a` AM/PM.
`HH` is the 24 hour format.

Also the locale must be correct, maybe explicitly set. Here English.